# update_or_create django admin imports

Tags: python, django

I have an `app` contains these models

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    rent_effective_date = ..
    income_period = ..
    property_market_rent =..
    number_of_family_group = ..
    cruser = ..
    prop_id = ..
    state = ..
    group =..
class FamilyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(..
    transaction =models.ForeignKey(Transaction,..
    ...
class FamilyMember(models.Model):
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, ..
    family_group = models.ForeignKey(FamilyGroup..
    name = models.CharField..
    date_of_birth = models.DateField..
    ....
```

Im trying to make `Imports` app that will accept `xlsx` files with some certain format.
after i imported the models from the other apps, therefore i've created a `model` that have a `field` for each `field` i n the above `models` , i removed a lot so it look readable.
im trying to make it `update_or_create` since i think its the best approach to do, since maybe in future maybe i want to update some fields. I have created the first `update_or_create` for `Transaction` but since `family_group` and `family_member` are childs of `Transaction` and `Inlines` i cant figure out how to apply this. the main idea is i have a transaction contains family_groups and family_members inside it .

```
class Batch(models.Model):
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    transaction_chp_reference = models.CharField(unique=True)
    transaction_rent_effective_date = models.DateField(..
    transaction_property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(..
    transaction_number_of_family_group = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(..
    family_group_name = models.CharField(..
    family_group_family_type = models.CharField(..
    family_group_alloc_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(..
    family_group_last_rent = models.DecimalField(..
    family_member_name = models.CharField(..
    family_member_contact_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(..
    family_member_surname = models.CharField(..
    family_member_partnered = models.BooleanField(..

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.batch)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.message = ''
       if self.transaction_chp_reference:
          trans, t = Transaction.objects.update_or_create(
              # filter on the unique value of `chp_reference`
              chp_reference=self.transaction_chp_reference,
              # update these fields, or create a new object with these values
              defaults={
                    'income_period':self.transaction_income_period,
                    'property_market_rent':self.transaction_property_market_rent,
                    'number_of_family_group':self.transaction_number_of_family_group,
                    'rent_effective_date':self.transaction_rent_effective_date,
                    'cruser':self.transaction_cruser,
                    'prop_id':self.transaction_prop_id,
                    'state':self.transaction_state,
            }
        )
        self.message += 'Transaction "' + str(trans.chp_reference) + '" Created\n'
            obj, mt = MaintenanceType.objects.update_or_create(
                name=self.family_group_maintenance_type,
                      )
            obj, ft = FamilySituation.objects.update_or_create(
                name= self.family_group_family_type,
            )
            obj, fg = FamilyGroup.objects.update_or_create(
                transaction=t,
                name=self.family_group_name,
                defaults={
                    'alloc_id':self.family_group_alloc_id,
                    'any_income_support_payment':self.family_group_any_income_support_payment,
                    'cra_amount':self.family_group_cra_amount,
                    'cra_eligibilty':self.family_group_cra_eligibilty,
                    'family_type':ft,
                    'ftb_a':self.family_group_ftb_a,
                    'ftb_b':self.family_group_ftb_b,
                    'last_rent':self.family_group_last_rent,
                    'maintenance_amount':self.family_group_maintenance_amount,
                    'maintenance_type':mt,
                    'name':self.family_group_name,
                    'number_of_additional_children':self.family_group_number_of_additional_children,
                }
            )
            self.message += 'Family Group "' + str(obj.name) + '" Created\n'
```

now im getting an error when try to import xlsx file:
`Cannot assign "False": "FamilyGroup.transaction" must be a "Transaction" instance.`
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 575, in update_or_create
obj = self.select_for_update().get(**kwargs)
File "E:\15-12\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 417, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
calculator.models.FamilyGroup.DoesNotExist: FamilyGroup matching query does not exist.
```

***UPDATE***
I have replaced the `save()` method with this code.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Batch)
def post_save_tranaction(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    message = ''
    if created:
        Transaction.objects.update_or_create(
        chp_reference=instance.transaction_chp_reference, defaults= 
       {rent_effective_date':instance.rent_effective_date,... , ... })
## now since FamilyGroup is a child (Foreignkey) to Transaction
## im not sure how to make it instance of Transaction
## FamilyMember is also a child of FamilyGroup and Transaction - same issue
## i tried this --->
    transactions = []
    transaction = Transaction.objects.all()
    for i in transaction:
        transactions.append(i.pk)
    FamilyGroup.objects.update_or_create(name=instance.family_group_name,
                                         transaction__in=transactions
                                        )
```

Comment: You should use foreign keys or something to keep all the models consistent

Comment: not necessary becz i will just assign the info imported from the xlsx file to the fields here

Comment: @AbdullaOsama- My suggestion and feel free to disagree. Have you considered using signals to move some of your save logic in a post_save signal. I would normally temper with the save() if I am doing some modification in the data that will be saved in that model.If there is any transaction that needs to happen in another model, I would use post_save.

Comment: @AbdullaOsama- Also, are these atomic transactions that you are doing inside the save() block. What happens if one of the transactions fails while the others go through? Should there be a rollback?

Comment: I had to take a look at the signals, since i havent use em before, looks interesting. I replaced `save()` with a `post_save()` now `Batch` is the sender, now i have 3 `models` `Transaction`, `FamilyGroup` and `FamilyMember` and Transaction is parent, i want to make `FG` and `FM` instaneces of `Transaction` not sure how to do this, please check my update, @SDRJ